# select & option, adding index alphabetically in php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, select, optgroup

I'm working on a website bilt with wordpress.
I've included a select type menu with the name and links of my children pages of one parent page.
everything works fine, my pages are sorted alphabetically ASC :

```
Bali
Bruxelles
Chicago
Edinburgh
Geneve
Los Angeles
Lyon
Miami
Paris
San Diego
San Francisco
Vancouver
Washington
Zurich
```

here is my code :

```
<div class="styled-select">
<?php

if(!$post->post_parent){

    $children = get_pages(array(
        'child_of' => $post->ID,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'sort_order' => 'ASC',
        'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    ));

}else{

    $children = get_pages(array(
        'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'sort_order' => 'ASC',
        'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    ));
}

if ($children) {
    echo '<select name="" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';
    echo '<option>'. 'A - Z' .'</option>';

    foreach($children as $child){
        //print_r($child);
        $permalink = get_permalink($child->ID);

        echo '<option value="'.$permalink.'">'.$child->post_title.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';

} ?>

</div>
```

I wanted to know if its possible to add automatically an alphabet index (width  in guess) inside my menu, like this. add "A" in  before all pages beginning with A (when there are pages beginning with A...), add "B" in  before all pages beginning with B, and so on...
Something who must look like this :

```
A
B
  Bali
  Bruxelles
C
  Chicago
D
E
F 
  Edinburgh
G
  Geneve
H
I
J
K
L
  Los Angeles
  Lyon
M
  Miami
N
O
P
  Paris
Q
R
S
  San Diego
  San Francisco
T
U
V
  Vancouver
W
  Washington
X
Y
Z
  Zurich
```

If anybody know who I can do it it would be much appreciate !
thanks a lot

Mattieu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use as follows (for demonstration only) :

```
    function getInitials($name){
//split name using spaces
$words=explode(" ",$name);
$inits='';
//loop through array extracting initial letters
    foreach($words as $word){
    $inits.=strtoupper(substr($word,0,1));
    }
return $inits;  
}
$currval = "";
foreach($children as $child){
    //print_r($child);
    $permalink = get_permalink($child->ID);
    $initial = getInitials($child->post_title);
    if($initial!='' && $currval != $initial) {
        $currval = $initial;
        echo '<optgroup>'.$initial.'</option>';
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$permalink.'">'.$child->post_title.'</option>';
}
```

Not checked though.. please check and return if you face any prob

---

In the case you need to show all alphabets, i can give you an idea to do so

```
function getInitials($name){
//split name using spaces
$words=explode(" ",$name);
$inits='';
//loop through array extracting initial letters
    foreach($words as $word){
    $inits.=strtoupper(substr($word,0,1));
    }
return $inits; 
}
$currval = "";


$alp = array('A'...'Z')

foreach($alp as $abc) {
    foreach($children as $child){
        //print_r($child);
        $permalink = get_permalink($child->ID);
        $initial = getInitials($child->post_title);
        if($initial!='' && $currval != $initial && $initial == $abc) {
            $currval = $initial;
            echo '<optgroup>'.$initial.'</option>';
        }
        echo '<option value="'.$permalink.'">'.$child->post_title.'</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: hello great ! thanks a lot ! that's what I've been trying to do, great... only one problem, it generates the <optroup>, in my source code generated I can see <optgroup>B</optgroup>, but nothing is displayed in my menu, only an empty line... and when it comes to city with two words, like San Francisco, I have this <optgroup>SF</optgroup>, instead of <optgroup>S</optgroup>... so I'm quite close to the result !!! here is my code including yours : https://gist.github.com/mattieumoreau/6790846,
thanks a lot for your help

Comment: well I fixed the display problem by replacing echo '<optgroup>'.$initial.'</option>'; by echo '<optgroup label="'.$initial.'""></optgroup>'; but how can I display only the first letter of the first word @SKV ? thanks ! –

Comment: thanks for your help @SKV the code you gave me is working great (I just added to display the letter). but I have one problem, it displays the first letter of each word of my strings... example : for San Francisco it displays SF, instead of "S"

https://gist.github.com/mattieumoreau/6791683

and is it possible even if I don't have any pages beggining with D, to get the "D" to be displayed in optgroup ? the idea is to have all the 26 letters to be displayed... thanks again for your help !

Comment: please check my anwser again, i have edited it.. please note its an idea for demonstration.

Comment: thanks ! sorry I didn't see your answer...
I added the code and check for errors, I can't find any, but It doesn't work and I get a blanck page instead... I must have done something wrong ??
https://gist.github.com/mattieumoreau/6791846

Comment: thanks a lot ! 
I'm trying also to get only the first letter of the first word...
for example on San Fransisco, I just want to display the "S".... here it displays SF, I'm trying to change the code with a new "explode" function, but without success, argggggg

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have again edited the code as per your need.

please check

```
<?php
function getInitials($name){
    //split name using spaces
    $words=explode(" ",$name);
    $inits='';
    //loop through array extracting initial letters
    foreach($words as $word){
        $inits = strtoupper(substr($word,0,1));
        break;
    }
    return $inits; 
}
$currval = "";
$alp = array('A','B','C','D','E','Y','S','Z');
//$children = array('Asin','Bali','Bruxelles','Chicago','Denmark','Edinburgh','Flag','San Francisco');
?>
<select name="test">
<?php
foreach($alp as $key => $abc) {
    $showinOpt = false;
    foreach($children as $child) {
      $permalink = get_permalink($child->ID);
      $initial = getInitials($child->post_title);
       if($initial == $abc) {
           if($currval != $initial) {
                $currval = $initial;
                echo '<optgroup label="'.$initial.'">'.$initial.'</optgroup>';
                $showinOpt = true;
           }
           echo '<option value="'.$permalink.'">'.$child->post_title.'</option>';
        }
    }
    if(!$showinOpt) {
        echo '<optgroup label="'.$abc.'">'.$abc.'</optgroup>';
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

Just add this after you got the $children array.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but using this method I don't get the children page ID in my function...
I guess I need to add something here $array1 = array('Asin','Bali','Bruxelles','Chicago','Denmark','Edinburgh','Flag');
I need to build my array with the $permalink = get_permalink($child->ID);
    $initial = getInitials($child->post_title);
do you know what I mean ?

Comment: yes I understand, but I need to get my children pages into this array  $array1 = array('Asin','Bali','Bruxelles','Chicago','Denmark','Edinburgh','Flag'); ... it has to be dynamic, you see ?

Comment: yes it works perfectly ! I did a mistake in my php coding but now everything is working perfectly fine ! thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: My pleasure, though i was also hoping for an upvote + acceptance, its okay no worries

Comment: with pleasuer, but how can I do this ? I'm new on this forum !

Comment: Hello Again @SKV, I'm using the code you help me to correct, the one to display A, B, C, etc indexes to my options in my select menu... it works fine... but I still have an issue with this.
I want to have an A only if a city in my list begins with A, if not, no A, and so on & I have sometimes 2 or 3 cities begining with N for example,  N for (new york, northampton...) and my city names inside the N have to be sorted alphabetically, as for other letters
here is my code, where I do it manually :
https://gist.github.com/mattieumoreau/6978866
would be nice if you have any idea of doin it ! thanks